# Discrepancy between the calculated index size and the real index size

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to rebuild an index because it's highly fragmented.

**Information:**

Miscrosoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (Enterprise Edition)

I have a big table (12,033,735,256 rows) with only one index. It's a non-clustered index with:

- Index key column: uniqueidentifier (16 bytes).
- Included columns: real (4 bytes), uniqueidentifier (16 bytes).
- Fill factor: 100.

The table has another column with an uniqueidentifier, but it's not considered by the index.

This index has probably not been reorganized or rebuilt in the last 4 years and has millions of new rows every day. As far as I know, the table hasn't changed drastically in this time (no changes in the data or the data types or added/dropped columns)

**Steps:**

I follow this MS guide to find out how much space I will need to rebuild the index: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/index-disk-space-example?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2008

Calculations:

Nonclustered index size: 12,033,735,256 rows * (16 + 4 + 16) bytes / 100% fill factor = 403.46 GB

As far as I know, I also need this amount of space for sorting into tempdb, so finally is 403.46 GB * 2 = ~807 GB to accomplish the rebuild operation.

**Problem:**

The real index size is 1,051 GB. I have seen it in the "index space" row of the table's storage information and it is the only index.

How can this be possible? Why it's not close to 403.46 GB? Are my steps correct?

Thanks.

Comment: From what you describe your table is lacking a primary key. This means the storage engine has to create a uniqueifier so it knows what row is what. When you defragment that massive index it is going to need a LOT of space to sort that. The question for me is why do you have a table with 12 billion rows and no primary key? And no clustered index?

Comment: Consider that part of the *reason* the index is fragmented is because it contains plenty of empty space where rows used to be. What is "page fullness" for the index? (Note that this is not the same as the fill factor.) I also seem to recall that heap tables in particular are prone to gathering dust in pages that are no longer used, something that `REORGANIZE` can fix. (`REBUILD` too, of course.) I don't recall the exact mechanics of that, though.

Comment: Also, Kendra Little has a nice blog article about some issues to consider at https://littlekendra.com/2016/10/13/should-you-rebuild-or-reorganize-indexes-on-large-tables-dear-sql-dba-episode-19/

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, you're right. There is not primary key. I think it's done in this way in a try to save memory and use two foreign key to identify each column, but there is not any kind of formal integrity restriction in these keys and they doesn't work as PK made from the combination of these keys.

2nd question: I think there is not a clustered index in order to save I/O, thinking that with a non-clustered index you can avoid to get the data from the variable that you are not interested in (and there are a lot of rows). Thats sounds reasonable for me, but I'm not sure if it's a good reason.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'll check page fullness. Either way, I need to rebuild the index. It has an average fragmentation of 97%.

Comment: If you have only a nonclustered index on your table you are crippling yourself. That table is known as a heap and the performance is horrific. Add to that using a guid which will almost always have really high fragmentation, unless you constantly defragment it, and you have a classic recipe for absurdly slow queries.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange. Your advices were perfect.